# Which Micrometer meter to use for exposing simple static application (non numeric) info from Spring?

Tags: spring, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, micrometer

I've read about Micrometer Gauge, Timers and DistributionSummary but all I want is to expose some basic application info from my Spring Boot application (ultimately on Grafana).

I have enabled the /prometheus endpoint which is displaying a host of open-metrics about my Spring boot application but I now want to start adding custom metrics. The first one is just the application version which could be in the format 5.6.3 (so string based).

Which Micrometer meter should I used to add this to the MeterRegistry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer of a gauge will work, but a better solution is to use the [commonTags](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_common_tags) feature of MicroMeter so all your meters have that 'version' tag.

`registry.config().commonTags("version", "5.6.3", "region", "us-east-1");`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I've found is to store required value as a Tag in a Gauge collection.

e.g.

```
meterRegistry.gaugeCollectionSize("app.info", Tags.of("version", "5.6.3), new ArrayList<String>())
```

and when I look at my /prometheus endpoint, I see the following which I can grab in Grafana:

```
app_info{version="5.6.3",} NaN
```